# How to Allow Facebook Access to Protected Content

Tags: facebook, comments, password-protection

I am using Facebook comments on password protected pages. I have recently found that when a new post is created I get the error 'facebook comments {page} is unreachable' and when I debug using Facebook's debug tool no ID is found. FB Namespace, meta tag and js are all inserted correctly and work fine on all non protected pages.

When I disable the password protection and refresh the page everything works fine and after being loaded correctly that once it seems to be fine when I re enable the password protection also.

So I guess Facebook needs to be able to access the page the first time to set it up in it's database?

Is there a way I can allow Facebook to access the page initially. For example in my verification function I could add:

```
if( can_user_view_content() || is_request_from_facebook() ){
    //echo content and comments
```

Does Facebook send a useragent string I could use or is there a better way than testing for user agent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Facebook's bot usually operates with the user agent header `FacebookExternalHit/1.1` or `FacebookExternalHit/1.0` (but the version number could increment at some point)

If you normally gate your content to logged in users but need the crawler to reach your page, note that you don't need to return the full content to the crawler provided that the open graph meta tags are returned to it 
(i.e put the same tags you'd use on the regular content for the login page also)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play with the user agent you've suggested. 
With access to the page it is only the main content and comments that are hidden (replaced with login form) so FB crawler can access the meta tags etc.